Copyright for PhD Thesis?
Which of the following copyrights is most suitable for a PhD thesis and how do each of them restrict the use of the ideas presented in the thesis?
1. Copyright © [Year], [My Name]. All Rights Reserved.
2. Copyright © [Year], [My Name]. This work is licensed under a CC BY-NC-ND 4.0 International License.
Under the following terms:
Attribution — You must give appropriate credit , provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made . You may do so in any reasonable manner, but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use.
NonCommercial — You may not use the material for commercial purposes .
NoDerivatives — If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you may not distribute the modified material.
No additional restrictions — You may not apply legal terms or technological measures that legally restrict others from doing anything the license permits.
Note 1: According to the university, I am free to choose any of the above copyrights for my thesis.
Note 2: The thesis will be published on this public website belonging to the French government : https://theses.hal.science/
Please also let me know for the Copyright © [Year], [My Name]. All Rights Reserved. Which option should I choose from the list in the screenshot below?

If you need additional information please let me know.

Depends upon your universities policies and possibly your funding agency if you have one. Personally, I would not release my thesis or dissertation into the public domain. You risk people publishing it on their own. For example, I have had people take government reports I have written, repackage them, and sell them on Amazon as books implying that I've written something I never wrote. You may also risk not being able to publish chapters in journals if you release the copyright.

@Richard Erickson, But without publishing the thesis in the public domain you are not able to explain precisely what you did in your thesis.

@EarlGrey , According to the university, I am free to choose any of the above copyrights for my thesis. Also, without publishing the thesis in the public domain you are not able to explain precisely what you did in your thesis.

"without publishing the thesis in the public domain you are not able to explain precisely what you did in your thesis."
This is doubtful at best, the "publishing the thesis" condition is neither sufficient (you may have paid someone to complete the writing) nor necessary (I do not need to read your thesis to check if you can do what you say you can do).
On the other hand, the thesis work usually results in some peer-reviewed publication: how precisely you got to these results is either explained in the paper or is part of your knowledge that you can show when inquired about.

@EarlGrey ,"I do not need to read your thesis to check if you can do what you say you can do". If I tell someone what I did, they can use or publish my ideas! So, what is the difference between publicly publishing a thesis and explaining ideas orally to someone?!!

@Questioner Note that public domain has a very specific meaning in copyright law, that is entirely distinct from simply making the document publicly available (i.e. publishing it).

@Anyon, By public domain I mean this public website belongs to the French government : https://theses.hal.science/

@Questioner very few people has the time to go through the whole thesis of a random person, while few people can listen to a 20 mintues talk covering the thesis subject.
If you are worried that someone publish your ideas, why don't you publish them first?

@EarlGrey , Your question is weird. I am disseminating my work among fellow experts in my field to increase its exposure, which naturally benefits me. However, safeguarding my rights is also a priority : Proper attribution is paramount if my ideas are published; my name should always be acknowledged.

@Questioner The French government may own the website, but that does NOT mean that works posted on that site are in the public domain. Works in the public domain do not have any copyright and anyone can use them as they see fit, without having to consult the original author. As best as I can tell, the HAL website does not require you to give up your copyrights when you upload to it, and in fact encourages you to put a licensing statement in your work. So uploading your thesis to that portal is not "putting it in the public domain". It's making it publicly available.

@EarlGrey Field dependent. In the humanities, the best work is a published book. Books are often seen as needed for a faculty position and a thesis often is the basis of one. There is a belief, real or imagined, that widespread dissemination of the work (not the ideas) will lower publisher interest in picking up the book.

"All Rights Reserved" means that rights that you have under copyright law are not granted to people who read your thesis. It's the same as doing nothing at all; you keep the rights you already have by virtue of being a creator of some copyrightable work. They can still read and cite the ideas if they can access it; they can use the material under whatever concepts of "fair use" or "fair dealing" or whatever the equivalent in copyright law is in your jurisdiction (examples might include reproducing for certain purposes like education). Presumably there is still a separate license you are granting to the repository; you should read that and see what it entails.
The CC BY-NC-ND 4.0 license is here: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/legalcode.en with a more plain-language summary here: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/
Both of these licenses are appropriate for a thesis; you should read and understand them and decide what makes best sense for you. If you have code or other materials that go along with your thesis, you may want to release those separately under a license appropriate to that material. If you've given other licenses to your work already as part of publishing, posting preprints, etc, then the license (or lack of license) you apply to your thesis does apply to the thesis itself but does not override more permissible licenses you've already granted to those parts.
Also, importantly, licenses cover the concept of copyright. They do not cover the concept of academic ethics. From an ethics perspective, it's necessary to cite when ideas are used regardless of the copyright license on the work.

Also worth noting that most places, the "all rights reserved" one does not actually do anythying, since that is the default for any work without needing a notice.

@TobiasKildetoft Made an edit to clarify that.

More the the point, copyright covers the particular work. Ideas can not be copyrighted.

@Jon Custer, NoDerivatives states: "If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you may not distribute the modified material." https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/. Therefore, it includes ideas, not just words and phrases.

@Questioner That's not what "no derivatives" means; derivatives are narrowly defined as derivatives of the copyrightable work like incorporation into a book of many articles. And it definitely can't include ideas, because ideas are not copyrightable anyways, as Jon pointed out, so you don't need the license to say that you can use the ideas, you can already use the ideas even for work that is "all rights reserved".

@Bryan Krause , So it's: "No rights reserved" ! ...

@Questioner Huh? No. That isn't what I'm saying at all, I don't know how you'd possibly get that impression. A license can't give you extra rights you didn't have in the first place. You can set conditions on rights you give up, but that's it.

So let me know for the Copyright © [Year], [My Name]. All Rights Reserved. Which option should I choose from the list in the screenshot that I have added to my question?

From a comment:

it depends what you want. If you want other people to be able to copy
and distribute your thesis (on condition that they provide full
attribution to you), the CC one is most suitable; if you don't want
people to be able to do that, the "all rights reserved" one is most
suitable.

Attribution of ideas, i.e. whether someone publish your ideas without referencing to you is a completely different topic and it is independent from which copyright form you use: it is their duty to properly cite your work, if it was known to them at the moment of submission.
Proper reference may even be a "Questioner, 2024, notes on a napkin" if it was so.

NoDerivatives states: "If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you may not distribute the modified material." https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/. Therefore, it includes ideas, not just words and phrases.

Ideas are not material

So let me know for the Copyright © [Year], [My Name]. All Rights Reserved. Which option should I choose from the list in the screenshot that I have added to my question?

Choose number 1.  You cannot revoke a Creative Commons license once granted, but you can add a Creative Commons license to all or part of your work later if that becomes useful.
Either license asserts your claim to the work.  See the comments which tell you that attribution is always required and that ideas cannot be copyrighted. Copyright protects the written work.

NoDerivatives states: "If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you may not distribute the modified material." https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/. Therefore, it includes ideas, not just words and phrases.

@Questioner  Nope.  Copyright protects, in this case, the words.  ND says you can't remix, transform, or build upon.  That "build upon" may be the source of confusion.  You can clearly extend and "build upon" an idea, but you do that with your own writing, and with proper citation where the writing of another is used.

So let me know for the Copyright © [Year], [My Name]. All Rights Reserved. Which option should I choose from the list in the screenshot that I have added to my question?

@Questioner I don't know. It depends on the regulation of your university, I guess. Saclay mentions that
"The substantial abstract of the thesis will appear as an appendix to the thesis, for consultation in the library and/or distribution on the Internet. In all cases, the choices made (choice of language for writing the thesis, format of the substantial abstract) must allow the entire French-speaking scientific community to access the research work presented for the doctoral degree." ( https://www.universite-paris-saclay.fr/sites/default/files/2023-02/guide_to_the_doctoral_defense.pdf  )

I meant Copyright © [Year], [My Name]. All Rights Reserved. is related to which licence option listed in the screenshot I added to my question ? Copyright ?

@Questioner I believe the only option that corresponds to choice 1 is  "Copyright."
